# Display specific column through PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

I have PortalMammals_species.csv which cotains following columns :

```
['record_id', 'new_code', 'oldcode', 'scientificname', 'taxa',
       'commonname', 'unknown', 'rodent', 'shrubland_affiliated']
```

I want to find out how many taxa are “Rodent” and Display those records by using PANDAS.
I am trying this:

```
Taxa =df["taxa"]=="Rodent"
print(Taxa.value_counts())
```

but this code giving me only value counts that are True :28 and False :27

How can I display only those records that are true?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOksT.png)

Comment: Your result is saying 28 are "rodents" and 27 aren't. If you want to count each animal, you need `df["taxa"].value_counts()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want a count of 'Rodent' only while still using value_counts(), you can try:

```
df['taxa'][df['taxa']=="Rodent"].value_counts()
```

Another option:

```
df['taxa'][df['taxa']=="Rodent"].count()
```

The PortalMammals_species.csv dataset I am seeing online also has a 'rodent' column, which is a 1/0 flag for rodent; if you have that column too, you could try

```
df['rodent'].sum()
```

**EDIT** in response to OP's comment:

To display the 'taxa' column only, filtered for Rodent:

```
df['taxa'][df['taxa']=="Rodent"]
```

To display the entire df filtered for Rodent:

```
df[df['taxa']=="Rodent"]
```

Comment: I want to select taxa column Display those records that are rodents. Value counts function show just true or false but not actual records

Comment: @AnasJamshed Try: df['taxa'][df['taxa']=="Rodent"] for that column only. And df[df['taxa']=="Rodent"] for the entire df filtered for Rodent only.

Comment: @AnasJamshed updated the answer

Comment: Thanks . df[df['taxa']=="Rodent"] is showing my desired output

Comment: @AnasJamshed I am glad it's working. Please accept the answer if it addresses your question.